# Date is not properly calculated in Java. Issue with zone

Tags: java, datetime

I have a date format stored in DB, for example:

```
Thu Aug 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I want to display the same date as output. Seems like I am missing something zone. It's evolving to be one day prior to this date.

I did the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter etFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mma 'ET'");
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ((Timestamp) date).toLocalDateTime().atZone(zoneId);
etFormat.format(zonedDateTime)
```

Output:

```
08/26/2020 at 08:00PM ET
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think `'ET'` means?

Comment: I got it from here : https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/convert-date-time-to-est-est5edt/

Comment: Sure, but what do you think it does? Why do you think so? (Hint: what do quotes signify?)

Comment: What database are you using? Is it Oracle? Are you using JDBC to retrieve the "date" from the database? If you are, can you [edit] your question and post the java code that you use to retrieve the date?

Comment: Also, please specify your system timezone.

Comment: Also what it the datatype in your database?

Comment: As an aside, the web site where you got that `'ET'` from is teaching you a bad habit. Better to use `v` for the zone abbreviation ignoring summer time (daylight saving time). Like `ET` for Eastern Time.

Comment: Database is mysql, datatype in database : Date, Datatype in Java end is also Data. There must be surely issue with Zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date is converted with timezone set to GMT.

```
final static String datePattern = "EEE MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z '('z')'";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern, Locale.getDefault());
simpledateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))

simpleDateFormat.format(givenDate)
```

Comment: Using `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat` and `TimeZone` is a serious and completely unnecessary step backward compared to the code in the question where you were using java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The classes you are using here are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome.

Answer (score 3):

In your database you have the date time with offset UTC-04:40 (which is 4 hr behind from UTC assuming America/New_York timezone). And when it converts into `Timestamp` it will be stores in UTC without offset which is `08/26/2020 at 08:00PM`.

So first convert the `Timestamp` into `Instant` of UTC and then convert the `Instant` into `ZonedDateTime` with the zone information

```
 ZonedDateTime dateTime = timestamp.toInstant()
                           .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                           .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
 etFormat.format(dateTime);     //08/27/2020 at 00:00PM ET
```

Answer (score 1):

The central issue is this:

`java.sql.Timestamp`, which is what e.g. `resultSet.getTimestamp()` returns, **does not contain any timezone data**. It is simply an instant in time, and it is stored as milliseconds since the epoch (jan 1st, 1970), UTC zone.

**This does not match what most DBs store**, because most DBs *do* in fact explicitly store the timezone with that. If your DB does not do this, or you picked a column type which does not do this, you should strongly consider changing that.

So, if the database has stored 'midnight in new york, aug 27th', and the database is forced by JDBC to put this in java.sql.Timestamp terms, there's nothing the DB engine can do about it, other than do its best, which is to return that exact time, in UTC terms. If you then print the UTC timestamp in human terms, you end up with '4 at night', and not 'midnight' (because new york is 4 hours earlier than UTC).

You then, with your code say: Okay, take the timestamp, turn it into a local date time (that'd be the notion of '27th of august, 4 o clock at night', without any inkling of in which czone that is in, and by itself not a thing that can ever be turned back into an epoch with more info), and then you put this at the new york zone, giving you '4 at night in new york', which is 4 hours later than where we started.

### Okay, but how do I fix this?

Every other answer (so far) is just giving you silly ways to fight the symptoms.

I propose you fix the disease.

The actual error occurs when you ask the DB to transfer the fully timezoned information from its tables into the timezoneless java.sql.Timestamp object. Stop doing that.

Don't call (I assume your column is called 'mark', fill in whatever it might be):

`resultSet.getTimestamp("mark")`.

Call:

`resultSet.getObject("mark", ZonedDateTime.class);`

or possibly try `LocalDateTime.class`, or possibly `OffsetDateTime.class`, but ZDT is preferred.

Then if that does not work, complain to your DB and/or JDBC driver because they're messing up and making it next to impossible to do timezone stuff properly when interacting with that DB from the java side.

### Actually, the DB should store just a moment-in-time

If truly the time being stored represents the notion of an 'instant in time' and not so much 'as humans would ever talk to you about it', then there are data types for that too, but convert your `java.sql.Timestamp` object to a `java.time.Instant` asap (via `.toInstant()`), or straight up ask for it: `resultSet.getObject("colName", Instant.class)` and have java and the db line up the datatypes straight away.

### Eh, whatever. Cures are for wussies, just work around it

Eh, well, the only thing you really need to do then is not to magically add 4 hours. This will do it:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = timestamp.toInstant()
                           .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                           .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

even if the tz stored in the DB is something else (it'll then give you that instant in time, but in new york, e.g. if the db has stored 'midnight in amsterdam', this will give you a time 6 hours earlier (or possibly 7 or 5, there are a few days in the year where things go ape due to US and europe having different shift days for daylight savings).

Comment: This seems wrong. OP doesn't show how they get `date`. But, presumably, a jdbc driver knows how to read a date from the DB into a timestamp correctly.

Comment: @Savior You can check the source code of java.sql.Timestamp and notice how there is absolutely no field in which one could store the timezone, and yet, e.g. psql's `timestamptz` type, do include this. This draws us the inevitable conclusion: I don't care how much you trust the database. It is _IMPOSSIBLE_ to transfer all data contained in e.g. a timestamptz into an instance of java.sql.Timestamp. Treating a j.s.Timestamp as a date is tricky and can go wrong; LocalDate is what you really wanted. What do you think .getObject(x, LocalDate.class) is all about?

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Although a `java.sql.Timestamp` is a wrapper around epoch milliseconds, it prints the time in the current JVM default time zone, and when a JDBC driver retrieves a timestamp (without time zone), it is required by the JDBC specification to interpret the timezone-less value in the JVM default time zone. Your explanation only works when the JVM default timezone is UTC (or at least offset 00:00).

Comment: Also, JDBC does not specify support for `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. Some drivers may support this, but it is a non-standard extension, and if they support it, they likely will only support it for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` types and not for `TIMESTAMP [WITHOUT TIME ZONE]` types.

Comment: What @MarkRotteveel said. If the DB column has a timezone, the JDBC driver can simply convert it to UTC to get an epoch timestamp that can be stored in the `Timestamp` object. If the column doesn't have a timezone, then it's either an epoch timestamp itself or wall clock time that can be interpreted as UTC (or local timzone) as well during the conversion to `Timestamp`.

Comment: Sure, the JDBC spec is clear on how a db engine is supposed to paper over the fundamental issue that j.s.Timestamp is an unsuitable receiver for the data contained in a timestamptz field. That doesn't change much. __transferring a timestamptz to java via a j.s.Timestamp is a dumb thing to do__ - and the fact that JDBC explains how to do it anyway is nice, but doesn't make it any less idiotic. _IF_ your db/jdbc combo supports .getObject(x, ZDT.class), which unfortunately they don't all do, then use that. And if it doesn't, then complain, because that is bad.

Comment: We've kind of gone on a tangent with timestamptz as an example. That type of column simply stores 8 bytes representing a UTC timestamp. It uses the server's timezone as that additional hint. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/be5c9f434c3ce68b9140f3ff929023e69cb2f984/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/TimestampUtils.java#L384-L401), using `getTimestamp` will handle that just fine. I'm not sure why you think it's a _dumb thing to do_. The resulting `Timestamp` object will be adjusted based on the timezone passed along in the jdbc connection.

Comment: 4 o'clock at night in amsterdam on the 28th is the precise same instant in time as 10 in the evening in new york on the 27th. j.s.Timestamp cannot differentiate between these two. Just impossible. They are .equals() to each other according to j.s.Timestamp. And yet, various dbs have various datatypes which CAN. That's my point. j.s.Timestamp is a crappy tool to represent such datatypes. There is no 'built-in' (e.g. callable without using .getObject) type in JDBC that can, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The format that you have used is not correct. I hope you will be able to understand the difference by comparing your pattern with mine. The reason why I've presented the parsing logic is that you have not made it clear the type of date-time. Whatever type it may be, it looks like you have a date-time string, `Thu Aug 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` which you want to parse into `ZonedDateTime` and display the same into the pattern of the date-time string you have. I guess, the main problem you are having is how to format the `ZonedDateTime` instance into the same form.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time string
        String dateStr = "Thu Aug 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";
        
        // Define the formatter for parsing
        DateTimeFormatter parsingFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss zX")
                                            .appendLiteral(" (")
                                            .appendGenericZoneText(TextStyle.FULL)
                                            .appendLiteral(")")
                                            .toFormatter();

        // Parse the given date-time into ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, parsingFormat);

        // Display in default format [i.e. zonedDateTime.toString()]
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
        
        
        
        // Define the formatter for output
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss z")
                                            .appendLiteral(" (")
                                            .appendPattern("zzzz")
                                            .appendLiteral(")")
                                            .toFormatter();
        
        // Get the string representation in the custom format
        String strDate = zonedDateTime.format(outputFormat);

        // Display the string representation in the custom format
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-27T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
Thu Aug 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

**Note:** By any chance, if you also have difficulty to convert the timestamp into `ZonedDateTime`, you can refer other answers on this page and use this answer to solve the problem with formatting.

Comment: I guess my comments were removed because they were "obsolete" once you edited your answer, but I still have questions. Why are you still presenting this parsing logic? The OP hasn't shown how they get their `date` object. Your starting point should be a `Timestamp` object like theirs. Can you also please explain what isn't correct about their format and how/why you came up with yours?

Comment: @Savior - I've added notes at the beginning of the answer to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, exclusively for your date work. Instead of getting a `Date` or `Timestamp` from your database, since JDBC 4.2 (in the case of MySQL that’s many years now) get a modern `LocalDate` from your result set. An example:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement("select your_date from your_table;");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        LocalDate date = rs.getObject("your_date", LocalDate.class);
        // Do something with date
    }
```

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day and without time zone. So this will relieve you of all time zone trouble.

If you want to print the start of the day in North American Eastern time zone to the user in the format used in the question:

```
    DateTimeFormatter etFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mma v");
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.AUGUST, 27);
    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = date.atStartOfDay(zoneId);
    String result = startOfDay.format(etFormat);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output from this example is:

> 08/27/2020 at 12:00AM ET

Do use pattern letter `v` for time zone in the format pattern rather than hard-coding `ET`. The latter will produce false and confusing results when one day a junior programmer feeds a `ZonedDateTime` in an other time zone into the code.

### What went wrong in your code?

It’s not clear to me how you got your `date` from your database. Apparently `date` even though declared a `Date` was really a `Timestamp` (a bad practice since the inheritance relationship between the two classes is really one of implementation, not a conceptual one) denoting the start of the day in UTC. `toLocalDateTime()` is a dangerous and often meaningless call: it uses the time zone of the JVM for converting the `Timestamp` to a `LocalDateTime`. At 0:00 UTC it is 8 PM the evening before in Eastern time zone, so your `LocalDateTime` becomes 2020-08-26T20:00. Next `atZone(zoneId)` only gives the correct time because `zoneId` happens to coincide with the JVM’s time zone used in the previous step.

### Link

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.